# How to send clicked object name and path to another component by context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to sending the clicked image name and path by context from one react content to another.
But every time it returns a null object.

Here comes the process of creating and providing and consuming the context:

Creating:

```
 import React from 'react';

const ImageContext = React.createContext()
export default ImageContext;
```

Providing:

```
import ImageContext from '../ImageContext';

 onFileChangeName = event => {
  this.setState({ selectedFileName: event.target.files[0].name });
  };
 return (
 
<ImageContext.Provider value={this.state.selectedFileName}>
  </ImageContext.Provider >
```

Consuming:

```
return (
        <ImageContext.Consumer>

            {value => (
       
                    <ImageEditor
                        includeUI={{

                            loadImage: {
                                path: value.path,
                                name: value,
                            },
                            
        </ImageContext.Consumer>
    );
```

Please inform me.

Comment: Where is your Provider ? Pls update your code

Comment: Context uses for passing common values into child components. Therefore, you need to define a context provider and pass it the value (whatever you want to use in the other child components). And then you can **consume the value**.

Comment: I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to use states and props in react js

You can know more about it in the link provided below

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-js-for-beginners-props-state-explained/

Comment: What you are saying is the lifting up method. My question here is related to the context method.